# Singapore REP renewal when posted overseas

Tags: resident-permit, singapore

I am currently working overeseas as an expat of foreign company registered in Singapore but my home country is still singapore. my cpf is contributed regularly by my singapore company and i have a house and property in singapore. my tax for non-salary income is also filed in singapore. my pr renewal is coming up now. I have 2 questions

1. should I apply online for renewal or appear in person
2. if my renewal application is rejected. is my current REP till may still valid and can i travel on it to come and apply again in person?

regards,
MR

Comment: You can apply online https://www.ica.gov.sg/PR/reentry/pr_reentry_apply I can’t find any reference to an existing REP being invalidated/cancelled if a renewal application is refused. Why do you think it might be?

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation as you some time ago.  It's going to be a judgment call by the officer based on how strong your ties to Singapore are, but one possible outcome (or, at least, my outcome) is that you will get a **one-year extension** to your REP.  The thinking here is that if you're serious about living in Singapore, then you can arrange to come back within that year.

FWIW, I was also getting paid by a Singapore company and contributing CPF, but I was told that I had not spent enough time in the country to be considered a resident anymore.  No house or property, but if you're not living in it, this is unlikely to help much.

Comment: +1, nice answer. I guess another factor might be whether the OP can demonstrate an clear intention to return, for example contractual end date to the overseas assignment and/or work visa expiry, within a timescale acceptable to Singaporean Immigration.